# AWS Amplify "Connection to website not secure"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amazon-route53, aws-acm

I have my frontend website hosted on **AWS Amplify**. The framework is **NextJS**.

Occasionally our users are encountering a weird error - `The Connection to www.<mydomain>.com is not secure. You are seeing this warning because site does not support HTTPS`.

I can confirm that I do have the SSL certificate registered in AWS Certificate Manager for both `<mydomain>.com` as well as `www.<domain>.com` URLs. I can see theirr CNAME entries in Route53.

Any help would be highly appreciated.